# how to iterate a folder containing jpg images and create a list of label and images in python? file name --> label.count.jpg

Tags: python, image, label, classification

My code,

```
def loadImages(path):
    imageList = listdir(path)
    loadedImages = []
    for image in imagesList:
        img = PImage.open(path + image)
        loadedImages.append(img)
    return loadedImages

path = os.listdir('.')

imgs = loadImages(path)

for img in imgs:
    img.show()
```

> Error:
>
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> ----> 1 imgs = loadImages(path)
> 2
> 3 for img in imgs:
> 4     img.show()
>
> in loadImages(path)
> 1 def loadImages(path):
> 2
> ----> 3     imageList = listdir(path)
> 4     loadedImages = []
> 5     for image in imagesList:
>
> TypeError: listdir: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or None,
> not list

Answer (score 0):

```
def loadimages(pathlist):
    loadedImages = []
    for image in pathlist:
        img = PIL.Image.open(image)
        loadedImages.append(img)
    return loadedImages


files = os.listdir("./")

labels = [i.split(".")[0] for i in files]
images = loadimages(files)
```